# In Prolog how can I cut redundant answers

Tags: prolog, backtracking, non-repetitive

I am working on a dictionary-like program with prolog, and my code goes like this:

```
define(car,vehicle).
define(car,that).
define(car,has).
define(car,four).
define(car,wheels).
define(wheels,round).
define(wheels,object).
define(wheels,used).
define(wheels,in).
define(wheels,transportation).


defined(X):-define(X,_).

anotherdefined(X):- \+ undefined(X).
undefined(X):- \+define(X,_).
```

I am trying to write a defined/1 predicate which will give me:

```
?-defined(X).
X = car ;
X = wheels ;
false.
```

Yet, my defined/1 gives me `X=car.` five times (naturally) for everytime it counters `define(car,_).`
and my anotherdefined/1 gives me only `true.` What is the method to stop prolog backtracking to the other instances of `define(car,_).`,and skip to `define(wheels,_).`?

Edit: I have written the following lines to get the result I want with givedefinedword/1,

```
listdefined(X):-findall(Y,defined(Y),Z),sort(Z,X).
givedefinedword(X):-listdefined(List),member(X,List).
```

**However** since I wanted an efficient predicate (which I will use in many others) it beats the purpose. This predicate does too much process.

Or, Would it be better to use a predicate that modifies the code? say prepares a list of defined words, and modifies it when new definitions are added.

Thanks.

Comment: See `bagof/3` and `setof/3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `define` to relate items and lists, like

```
definelist(car, [vehicle, that, has, four, wheels]).
% etc.
defined(X) :- definelist(X, _).
```

then `defined` will no longer produce duplicates, nor require linear space.

Of course, a query `define(X, Y)` must now be performed as `definelist(X, L), member(Y, L)`. If you want this to be efficient as well, you may need to duplicate all definitions.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is time  for me to start thinking in terms of Lists. What do you mean by "you may need to duplicate all definitions"?

Comment: @MericUsta That you'd `define(car, vehicle)` as well as my suggested `definelist`, and put all definitions in both predicates. I don't actually recommend that, but if speed is important, there are ways to automate it so you don't have to duplicate everything by hand.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with your program? It seems that you want to have facts in the form:

"A car is a vehicle that has four wheels"

"Wheels are round objects used in transportation" (a bit vague)

How are you going to use these facts? @larsmans suggestion if perfectly fine, if you want to just have your statement as a "sentence". It really depends what you will do with the information though.

Consider structuring the information in your database:

```
is(car, vehicle).
is(bicycle, vehicle).
is(boat, vehicle).
has(car, wheel(four)).
has(car, motor).
has(bicycle, wheel(two)).
```

Given this database, you can at least ask a question like, "what vehicles are there?", "does a bicycle have a motor?", or maybe, "how many wheels does a car have?", or "which vehicles have no wheels?"

```
?- is(X, vehicle).
?- has(bicycle, motor).
?- has(car, wheel(N)).
?- is(X, vehicle), \+ has(X, wheel(_)).
```

and so on.

Once you have defined your problem better, you can define your data structures better, which will make writing a program to solve your problem easier.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, it gives me some good insights. Right now I am more concerned about the definitions of words.. (currently just bogus definitions of course) But it might come to categorizing later as well.